# Why isn't my npm install working with my project?

Tags: windows, npm

I am trying to run my code, but the thing is that it doesn't run. It always comes up with an error message. I git cloned the repo, then `npm install` then when I run `npm dev run` it completely fills the box with error. How do I fix this?

[image: The picture]

Comment: few tips to improve your question : Copy paste the error instead of the screenshot. Also explain what other suggestions you already tried. There might already be similar SO posts. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package.json file is not located on the directory where you are running your command from. In order to get into your project use the following command:

```
cd project_name
npm install 
npm i // shorthand
```

If you are creating a new project, run the following command to initialize a new project:

```
npm init -y
```

The -y flag will skip some questions. It's optional

Good Luck :)